# Hibernate, Spring JPA, ManyToMany set query: Could not determine appropriate instantiation strategy - no matching constructor found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a `@ManyToMany` relationship between `Dog` and `Command`. I'm trying to get all dogs and their commands, using a `Query` (in order to exclude getting any additional data that can be in the `Dog` class), however it fails, despite the constructor being valid:

**Dog.java**:

```java
@Entity(name = "dogs")
public class Dog  {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "dog_sequence",
        sequenceName = "dog_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "dog_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "dog_command",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "dog_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "command_id")})
    private Set<Command> commands;

    public Dog() {}
    
    public Dog(Long id, String name, Set<Command> commands)  {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.commands = commands;
    }
...
```

**Command.java**:

```java
@Entity(name = "commands")
public class Command  {
    private enum CommandEnum  {SIT, JUMP, VOICE}

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "command_sequence",
        sequenceName = "command_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "command_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "command", unique = true)
    private CommandEnum command;
...
```

**DogRepository.java**:

```java
public interface DogRepository extends JpaRepository<Dog, Long> {
    
    @Query("select new com.example.demo.story.model.Dog(d.id, d.name, d.commands) from dogs d inner join d.commands c")
    List<Dog> findDogsWithCommands();
    
}
```

**DogController.java**:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/dog")
public class DogController {
    private DogRepository dogRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DogController(DogRepository dogRepository) {
        this.dogRepository = dogRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("all")
    @CrossOrigin
    public List<Dog> getStoriesNamesPictures()  {
        List<Dog> dogs = this.dogRepository.findDogsWithCommands();
        
        return dogs;
    }
}
```

I get the

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not determine appropriate
> instantiation strategy - no matching constructor found and one or more
> arguments did not define alias for bean-injection

error.

I can't just use `dogRepository.findAll()`, because the `Dog` class may have more data that I don't want to pull from the database (from other join tables).

While in raw `SQL` doing this would have been a matter of a single `SQL` query:

```sql
SELECT id, name, command FROM dogs d INNER JOIN commands c ON d.id = c.dog_id;
```

It doesn't seem to be possible to do in Spring Data? Does it mean I would have to fire a second `SQL` query, when inside the `DogController`?

What is the optimal way of dealing with a situation like this?

**EDIT**:

I made this work with this native query:

```
    @Query(value = "select d.id, d.name, c.command from dogs as d inner join dog_command as dc on d.id = dc.dog_id " +
        "inner join commands as c on dc.command_id = c.id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Dog> findDogsWithCommands();
```

But, perhaps, there are better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit difficult to solve.

The best way to fetch a limited set of attributes for entities are projections. A projection is an interface, a class or a record, that takes the desired attributes:

```
public interface LimitedDogAttributes {
    Long getId();

    String getName();
}

@Query("SELECT d.id AS id, d.name AS name FROM Dog d")
List<LimitedDogAttributes> findDogsWithCommands();
```

Apparently this doesn't work with collection attributes as expected. The result is a list entry for each row with only a single DogCommand in each collection:

```
public interface DogWithCommands {
    Long getId();

    String getName();

    Set<DogCommand> getCommands(); // Filled with only one collection item per result entry.
}

@Query("SELECT d.id AS id, d.name, c AS commands AS name FROM Dog d INNER JOIN d.commands c")
List<LimitedDogAttributes> findDogsWithCommands();
```

As long as all collections of Dog are lazy loaded there shouldn't be much impact of reading more (scalar) attributes as desired. Then the right solution is a `JOIN FETCH`:

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM Dog d WHERE d.commands IS NOT EMPTY")
List<Dog> findDogsWithCommands();
```

Comment: `DogWithCommands` doesn't seem to be used? I replaced `FROM Dog` with `FROM dogs`, because my table name is `dogs`. Then I get `No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.example.demo.story.model.Dog]` error

Comment: See my edits. nnn